# Make div overflow-y scroll start at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, meteor

I have a div with content being added to it. It is scrollable and I want to make the scrolling start from the bottom and update each time a new item is added.

I tried:

`var divName = document.getElementById("divId");
 divName.scrollTop = divName.scrollHeight;`

This does not work however, and when I console.log divName.scrollTop at the end, it is still 0 as it was in the beginning. If it helps, I am using Meteor.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('#divId').scrollTop($('#divId').prop("scrollHeight"));
```

assuming you've got jQuery

Comment: I tried that in the Template.flight.rendered function

Comment: Any way to make this work for a div that is not currently visible? (display:none)